# Using xpath to select part of xml

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a large xml file on the server. However, I need a part of that xml file so that i can bind it to XMLDATASOURCE.This is a part of my xml file:

```
       <Item Text="Reports" Navigateurl ="Reports/Default.aspx">
          <Group>
             <Item Text="Customers" NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/Default.aspx">
                      <Group>
                             <Item ... />
                              <Item.. />
                                ..... 
                       </Group>
            </Item>
```

in this way I have items in group tag. So, now i have a xml datasource which I later bind to RadSiteMap. This is the code I wrote in C#:

```
          XmlDataSource XmlDataSource1 = new XmlDataSource();
          XmlDataSource1.DataFile = "~/Menu.xml";
          XmlDataSource1.XPath = "//Item[@Text='Customers']";
          XmlDataSource1.DataBind();
           SiteMap1.DataBind();
        SetSiteMapLevel();

           <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server"  
            DataFile="~/Menu.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>
           <telerik:RadSiteMap runat="server" ID="SiteMap1" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1"  
              OnNodeDataBound="SiteMap1_NodeDataBound" ShowNodeLines="true">
```

It works fine but it displays in thos fashion:

```
          Customer
            group 
              ItemName1
               ..........
```

However, I dont want group tag to appear. Changes can be made to xml file but I just want to find if there is any way I can make group tag to not appear. Kindly let me know of the solution.

Comment: You can filter using XSLT. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605761/62576) for a pretty good example (with code).

Comment: Can you post the template your RadSiteMap is using?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this XPath it should work fine

```
XmlDataSource1.Xpath = "//Item[@Text='Customers']/Group";
```

This should give you what is inside the group tag customers

Comment: I have several other items too in the next group tag. At that moment, I need to display customer, items, items etc. with this example i get group tag at the second item list

Comment: Can you please post a better example showing the structure of your XML? Better yet can you post the result of a given sample input?